# RubyGems displaying the Source Code URL is not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have multiple GEMs on RubyGems and some of them show the Source Code link and some do not.

I am under the impression that all you need to do to set the source code link is set the `source_code_uri` meta data in the `.gemspec`

Is there another setting that needs to be configured?

```bash
# This one Works
spec.metadata['source_code_uri'] = 'https://github.com/klueless-io/handlebars-helpers'

# This one does NOT work
spec.metadata['source_code_uri'] = 'https://github.com/klueless-io/cmdlet'
```

[Handlebars-Helpers GemSpec](https://github.com/klueless-io/handlebars-helpers/blob/master/handlebars-helpers.gemspec)

[Cmdlet GemSpec](https://github.com/klueless-io/cmdlet/blob/main/cmdlet.gemspec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking into the [`cmdlet.gemspec`](https://github.com/klueless-io/cmdlet/blob/main/cmdlet.gemspec) which is the gem that is missing information on Rubygems, then there are these lines:

```
spec.metadata['homepage_uri']     = spec.homepage
spec.metadata['source_code_uri']  = 'https://github.com/klueless-io/cmdlet'
spec.metadata['changelog_uri']    = 'https://github.com/klueless-io/cmdlet/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md'
```

and then below in the same file:

```
spec.metadata = {
  'rubygems_mfa_required' => 'true'
}
```

That means the way how you set `rubygems_mfa_required` resets the whole `spec.metadata` hash.

Just change the `rubygems_mfa_required` assignment to the following and it will work after the next gem push to Rubygems:

```
spec.metadata['rubygems_mfa_required'] = 'true'
```